# Creating a torrent file with monotorrent: How do I add webseeds?

Tags: .net, mono, seed, monotorrent

I have been looking at [monotorrent](http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/monotorrent) and while investigating the whole bittorrent thing I saw that a torrent file may also specify web seeds, which are basically standard HTTP downloads but which can work e.g. as an initial seed.

I have also seen in the [release notes](http://projects.qnetp.net/news/show/6) of monotorrent 0.8 that they

> Added the ability to easily add webseeds to torrents created with the TorrentCreator.

However, I can't figure out how. There is a way to add custom key/value pairs to a torrent file through the TorrentCreator, but what is the right *incantation* to get webseeds incorporated into a torrent file with the aid of the monotorrent TorrentCreator class?

Comment: "MonoTorrent is a cross platform and open source implementation of the BitTorrent protocol." It's a .NET DLL. Definitely a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that was interesting...first to superuser and back to stackoverflow. I can understand if people say it's not programming related, since it's more about the torrent protocol itself, but anyways. If you want it closed, close, but don't migrate anymore.

The correct key to store into the torrent file is the "url-list", it's value the url to be used as web seed. With monotorrent this can be done through the "AddCustom" method on the TorrentCreator class. The BEncoded... classes will allow you to either define a single url, or several URLs that can be used as web seeds.